# Synonyms for "multiple things that reside in the same location"

Tags: single-word-requests

Synonyms for "multiple things that reside in the same location" - I can think of "colocated," which I've only seen in an engineering context. Do any other words fit the bill?

Comment: 'colocated' sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try juxtaposed from [juxtapose](http://m.wordnik.com/words/Juxtapose)

> To place (two or more objects) close
>   together; place side by side.

or even [cohabit](http://m.wordnik.com/words/cohabit)

> To dwell together; inhabit or reside
>   in company or in the same place or
>   country.

Comment: Given that `cohabit` also means "to live together as spouses" -- i.e., screw -- you might want to consider a different word.

Comment: @Malvolio good point - I think most people know this meaning but I think you can use the other sense if you establish the context properly

Comment: if a word has one meaning with a sexual or suggestive meaning, I've noticed, that meaning tends to crowd out other meanings.  When was the last time you heard `ejaculate` to mean "say abruptly" or `crotch` to mean "the point where a tree branch joins the trunk".  Even harmless words like `ball` and `blow` can be causes for merriment.

Comment: @Malvolio this might just be a matter of perspective but cohabit doesn't exactly have the same sexual or suggestive meanings vs. the words that you just mentioned - I might be in the minority with that observation but that's how I see it. I don't see anybody having fun in a bar with a word like "cohabit" :P (unless it has something to do with something that nuns wear - but that would be another matter :P )

Answer (score 3):

How about

> coexisting

I think this might be too vague for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about *co-ubietous*?

Outside of narrow, technical and philosophical contexts, [ubiety](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ubiety) means "the state of being located somewhere particular," which seems just the right start for what you're seeking.

Comment: Nice, way to pull out the big guns. But I don't believe the adjective form is a real word.

Comment: @Jasie - I find nothing improprietous about this "co-ubietous."  If you remain dubious, perhaps you could try "co-ubious?"