# Adjective for "happened at the same place"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

We have the adjective *simultaneous* for meaning "happened at the same time". So what is the adjective for "happened at the same place", *simul...*

Note: Simultaneous stuff *could* happen at different locations. So, "same place" adjective should have the *possibility* of different times of occurence, ryt??

Comment: Similar: [Synonyms for “multiple things that reside in the same location”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24481)

Comment: Neither response so far seems to answer your question. Nothing springs to mind. Perhaps you could try adding "too" to your adverbial phrase identifying place ???

Comment: Like?? An example??

Comment: If you're asking me, "He bought his at Sainsbury's too".

Comment: @Ross Murray Yeah. Got that now

Answer (score 1):

The term *coincident* can be used to mean either "ocurring at the same time" or "occuring at the same place". The related verb *coincide* was brought up in an answer to a similar question: [A word for 'to exist in the same place as something else'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44358/a-word-for-to-exist-in-the-same-place-as-something-else)

The space-related definition of *coincident* is the first in the Oxford English Dictionary (OED):

> 1. Occupying the same place or portion of space.

The examples that the OED gives to illustrate this definition seem to come from optics.

I don't know of a word that clearly refers to space and not time and has this exact meaning. The [Merriam Webster thesaurus entry for *coincident*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/coincident) suggests the following synonyms for the sense "occupying the same space":

> coextensive, coinciding, conterminous, coterminous

and the following "related" words:

> allover, overlaying, superimposed, superposed, underlying
>   conjoining, crisscrossing, intersecting, overlapping
>   coaxial, concurrent, convergent
>   congruent, conjunctional