# Word for "Occur At The Same Location"

Tags: single-word-requests

"Simultaneous" means at the same time.

*"(Insert Word)"* means at the same location.

*(For people that like physics out there, I'm studying special relativity...and I hate the fact that my notes say: "Events that are simultaneous and **happen at the same location** in one reference frame are simultaneous and **happen at the same location** in all reference frames").*

There HAS to be a shorter way to say it.

Thanks!

Comment: "Colocated" means at the same location, but doesn't fit neatly into your example.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks! Yep, it sounds a bit weird...it fits though! I'm going to use that for now.

Comment: They are **temporally and spatially coincident**. Does sound odd but works. Good Luck.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: "Adjective for 'happened at the same place'"  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/429534/14666

Comment: Possibly: "Events that are simultaneous and **are localised to** one **particular** reference frame are simultaneous and happen **locally** in all reference frames".

Answer (score 2):

There is "co-located", but that is usually analogous to "synchronized": we deliberately put them at the same point in space (or time), it wasn't just an accident.

There are also "convergence", "intersection", even "collision". Since things cannot be in the same spot (simultaneously), how about "adjacent" or "adjoining"?